# backcolor of a label lost on postback when using Eval to set it

Tags: asp.net, backcolor, partial-postback

I have a datalist in my website and each data item has a label with backcolor. The datasource is set and I have a label with backcolor which is set from a color Code in datasource :

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="RptColor" DataSourceID="DSColor" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RpLblColorCode" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("ColorCode").ToString()) %>' Width="20px" Height="20px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

the problem is that when I press a button and postback occurs the back color would be gone! ... I have an updatepanel on the page. 
please help me

Comment: Please write your code behind.

Comment: I don't write anything in code behind .. I just have this code for datasource in html :    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DsColor" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:arrecoconnection %>"
        OnSelecting="DSProdPic_Selecting" SelectCommand="Select ColorID,ColorCode,ColorName  from  GetColorTable(@PIDREf) ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PIDREf" QueryStringField="PIDREf" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: yes it is all in an update panel

Comment: It is hex code.. I've tried your code and I get this error ==> Specified cast is not valid

Comment: Do you know how to **Inspect Element** ? If yes after post back inspect your label and see the bg property value. Do you have another databound in update panel? Do they work truly?

Comment: I don't know how to inspect element and I have another databound in the updatepanel and it works correctly ... all of the other columns in the daatabound with backcolor are showing correctly .. the problem is just the backcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` instead of `Color.FromName`. You can change your code to this:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="RptColor" DataSourceID="DSColor" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server"
      ID="RpLblColorCode" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("ColorCode").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```